# How to make multiple divs sortable on Zepto

Tags: javascript, draggable, zepto

I must use Zepto instead of jQuery (https://zeptojs.com/), 
Also I use drag'n'drop library for Zepto, [zepto-dnd](http://ma.rkusa.st/zepto-dnd/). No other 'big' libraries can be used.

With the following code everything works fine.

```
<script src="https://zeptojs.com/zepto.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/rkusa/zepto-dnd/22e6a97788027d6e3e5b5d6f07791ace6a5465d9/zepto-dnd.js"></script>
<ul class="list" id="example1">

    <li>ItemA</li>
    <li>ItemB</li>
    <li>ItemC</li>
    <li>ItemD</li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#example1').sortable({})
  })
</script>
```

However my list should look something like:

```
<ul class="list" id="example1">

    <li><div id="something"><span>DIVA</span><span>SpanA2</span></div></li>
    <li><div id="something"><span>DIVB</span><span>SpanB2</span></div></li>
    <li><div id="something"><span>DIVC</span><span>SpanC2</span></div></li>
    <li><div id="something"><span>DIVD</span><span>SpanD2</span></div></li>
</ul>
```

And now everything breaks, dragging doesn't work well, etc. Can something be done in this situation?

Comment: Maybe you can wrap the spans together and try again ?

Comment: The problem is that things start to break even if li element is  <li><div>DIV</div></li>.

Comment: How do things start to break? why not just use divs? is there a reason you have to use `li`? explain more as to how it works, or how you want it to work, where it fails and how, describe your problem some more please.